# Run shell script from Vim with currently open file as argument

Tags: shell, vim, lilypond

I've just started using Vim.

Here is a shell script which I use frequenty from within [BBedit](http://barbones.com/products/bbedit/).

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=$(basename "${BB_DOC_PATH##*/}" .ly)
directory=${BB_DOC_PATH%/*}/

cd "${directory}"

lilypondPDFoutput="${directory}"$filename".pdf"

/Applications/Lilypond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/  lilypond -dno-point-and-click -ddelete-intermediate-    files "$BB_DOC_PATH"

wait

open "${lilypondPDFoutput}"
```

BB_DOC_PATH is a variable which represents the path of the currently open file. (e.g. `/Users/me/Documents/file.ly`)

How would I go about placing this script in my .vimrc, and invoking it with simple command like `:typeset`?

Note: I am typesetting a [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asked how to place the script in the .vimrc. This gets just a little tricky because of the odd way Vim import files do line continuation. It would be something like this:

```
command Typeset call Typeset()
fun Typeset()
    let $TYPESET_PATH = expand("%:p")
    let $TYPESET_ROOT = expand("%:p:r")
    let $TYPESET_DIR = expand("%:p:h")
    !sh -icx '
    \ cd "${TYPESET_DIR}"
    \; lilypondPDFoutput="${TYPESET_ROOT}.pdf"
    \; /Applications/Lilypond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/lilypond -dno-point-and-click "$TYPESET_PATH"
    \; wait
    \; open "${lilypondPDFoutput}"
    \'
endfun
```

Here's what is actually now working for me in quite a different environment (Lilypond/Win32; Vim for Cygwin).

```
" Quick compile command for Lilypond.
command Typeset call Typeset()
fun Typeset()
  let $TS_NAME = expand("%:t")
  let $TS_DIR = expand("%:p:h")
  let $TS_PDF = expand("%:t:r") . ".pdf"
  !sh -icx ' cd "${TS_DIR}" && lilypond "${TS_NAME}" && cygstart "${TS_PDF}" '
endfun
```

Notes: Lilypond/Win32 does not understand forward-slash paths. Therefore I eliminated the path in its argument. You could do the same. You have already set the path with "cd". Also for my environment I took out the point and click option, as well as the "wait", and changed "open" to "cygstart". At that point the shell part was short enough I did not need the rather arcane line continuation demanded by Vim. At the same time I added shortcut operators so that an error at any stage would stop the process.

Comment: I pasted your function into my .vimrc, but running :Typeset throws an error - see the modification of my question above.

Comment: I can try to help debug it, so I'll need to know specifics of the error that you're getting.

Comment: Okay, that looks like a bonehead copy and paste error on my part. Delete the semicolon that precedes the "cd". Since I can't reproduce your environment exactly on my system, we may well run into other bugs before we get it working.

Comment: Oops! It looks like you responded to my comment before I finished editing my question above.

Comment: The line which reads \; /Applications/Lilypond.app... should be changed to \; /Applications/Lilypond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/lilypond -dno-point-and-click "$TYPESET_PATH"

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like:

```
:!your_script %
```

If you have your_script in the PATH it should work fine. See [:!](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:!) and [file modifiers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%:.) for docs.